# Unity static value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a countdown timer, and when that timer end it goes to a game over scene that i can press to exit. The problem is when i try to start a new game it goes automatically to the game over scene because the time already passed.

```
 private static float timer = 30f;

 void Update () 
 {
  timer -= Time.deltaTime;
  timerSeconds.text = timer.ToString("f0");
  if (timer <= 0) 
  {
   Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);
  }

 }
```

How do reset it properly?

Comment: `if (timer <= 0) 
  {
   timer = 30f;
   Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);
  }`?

Comment: But what do i do? Do i remove the static?

Comment: replace `if (timer <= 0) 
  {
   Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);
  }` with `if (timer <= 0)    {    timer = 30f;    Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);   }`?

Comment: wow it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You never reset the `timer` and since it is `static` it keeps it's value after scene changes.

Depending a bit on your exact needs

- Either simply don't make it `static`
- reset it on game over

  ```
   if (timer <= 0)    
   {    
       timer = 30f;    
       Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);  
   }
  ```
- reset it at the start of a scene

  ```
   private void Start()
   { 
       timer = 30; 
   }
  ```